# projection error on Leaflet map

Tags: leaflet, geojson, proj

I am trying to add a converted shapefile (now a geojson) to a Leaflet basemap, using EPSG 26986, so I tried using proj4leaflet to reproject it. However, I keep getting an error message "phi2z has NoConvergence" - in fact, I seem to be getting one message for each point feature in the shapefile (there are over 800). I'm not sure why I'm getting this message - anyone have any thoughts?

```
Proj4js.defs["EPSG:26986"] = "+proj=lcc +lat_1=42.68333333333333 +lat_2=41.71666666666667 +lat_0=41 lon_0=-71.5 +x_0=200000 +y_0=750000 +ellps=GRS80 +datum=NAD83 +units=m +no_defs";
var map = L.map('map').setView([42.317007, -71.088560], 12);
L.tileLayer('http://{s}.tile.cloudmade.com/655da89c06dd43a7aee306e594341325/997/256/{z}/{x}/{y}.png', {
    attribution: 'Map data &copy; <a href="http://openstreetmap.org">OpenStreetMap</a> contributors, <a href="http://creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/2.0/">CC-BY-SA</a>, Imagery © <a href="http://cloudmade.com">CloudMade</a>',
    maxZoom: 16
}).addTo(map);

$.getJSON("image_locations.geojson", function(data) {
    data.crs={
        "type": "name",
        "properties": {"name": "urn:ogc:def:crs:EPSG::26986"}
        };
    L.Proj.geoJson(data).addTo(map);
});
```

live version here: http://altani.continuation.org/trilobites/leaflet.html

Answer (score 1):

Took a look at this in the JavaScript debugger, and found that you are missing the `+` in front of `lon_0`, which causes it to fail to parse the `lat_0` and `lon_0` definitions:

```
+proj=lcc +lat_1=42.68333333333333 +lat_2=41.71666666666667 +lat_0=41 lon_0=-71.5
```